# Regex not working in Firefox, but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I have this regex expression:

```
var message = message.replace(/<a.+?data-pageid=(?:"|')(\d+)(?:"|').+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
```

It works fine for Chrome and cturns this text...

```
'some text <a contenteditable="false" data-pageid="2">some more text</a>'
```

... into this text...

```
'some text @[2]'
```

However, for Firefox it doesn't work. There's no error notification either. It just seems to "ignore" that regex. Any ideas?

Comment: var message = message.replace(/<a.+?data-pageid=(?:"|')(\d+)(?:"|').+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');

Comment: Works in Firefox 36.0.4: https://jsfiddle.net/uajazqkp/

Comment: might i suggest using a DOM parser?

Comment: Is the expression in a <script> tag rather than a separate .js file? If so, it may be an issue with escaping of angle brackets.

Comment: An [example using a DOM parser](https://jsfiddle.net/uajazqkp/2/) (jQuery).

Comment: Works fine here https://regex101.com/r/nI4kU6/1

Comment: It's working OK in FF37.0.1. What version of FF are you seeing it fail in?

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to declare this as a *new* variable based on a variable with the *same name*?

Original:

```
var message = 'some text <a contenteditable="false" data-pageid="2">some more text</a>'
var message = message.replace(/<a.+?data-pageid=(?:"|')(\d+)(?:"|').+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
```

On Firefox 36.0.1 (and others, see comments above), this sets `message` to `some text @[2]`.

Remove the second declarative:

```
var message = 'some text <a contenteditable="false" data-pageid="2">some more text</a>'
message = message.replace(/<a.+?data-pageid=(?:"|')(\d+)(?:"|').+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
```

This will still work where the original worked, but may work in places that handle scope differently.  I'm guessing at the problem since I cannot reproduce it.

To better troubleshoot the problem, please provide your Firefox version and a sample implementation.